# Disable Parent Component actions from Child Component (WebView Comp)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm using this [Gesture Responder](https://github.com/hannigand/GestureResponder). It's a simple wrapper that fires an action when you swipe.

I also created a Media Player component that displays a YouTube video that allows a user to touch and play the video within that screen. This is also using the React Native `<WebView />` component.

I wrapped the entire screen with this Gesture Responder and it works. Swiping fires the action I want it to. Now the main problem here is that the Media Component will no longer play videos. Instead, touching the Video is seen as a Swipe Gesture and activates the action.

Is there a way we can tell the Media Player Component to not pay attention to the Gesture Responder?

`<MediaPlayer parentCompFunction={false} />`

I also tried doing something like this. It works but it's also completing messing with the styles of this screen. Tried fixing the styles but couldn't do so.

```
<View>
 <GestureResponder>
   <View> 
   </View>
 </GestureResponder/>
 <MediaPlayer />
 <GestureResponder>
   <View> 
   </View>
 </GestureResponder/>
</View>
```

Comment: `GestureResponder` renders a `View` that renders its `children`. Are the styles fixed if you don't nest the `View` in the `GestureResponder`?

Comment: Not sure how to go about doing that? Do you mean removing the `View` component from `GestureResponder`? If so, what should I be returning instead?

Comment: whatever children you passed to the nested `<View>`.