# How to render a View within a View without impacting styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm rendering a `View` that will display a number of components. Everything looks the way it should when I'm not using the `nestedContainer`. Each component is spaced out the way it should and it's aligned properly. Now if I add the `View` with the `nestedContainer` style, it no longer applies `space-around` to the `HandRolledIcon` and `UserName` component. How do I work around this and make sure those components within the nested View uses the styles I want?

[(This question is related to my other question which contains more details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638773/disable-parent-component-actions-from-child-component-webview-comp)

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.nestedContainer>
    <HandRolledIcon style={styles.hrIcon} />
    <UserName style={styles.userName} />
  </View>
</View>

container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
nestedContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
hrIcon: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
userName: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know what you're trying to achieve, But I feel u must brush up your flex-box knowledge.

Check out these links it might help you

- https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/
- https://facebook.github.io/yoga/docs/getting-started/

One way of achieving your result is giving flexGrow:1 (flex: 1 kind of works the same in react-native) to your nested container, which will make your nested container view to occupy all the extra space.

```
nestedContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems: 'center', // <--- This can be removed based on your requirements since its already given to the parent view
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
```

NOTE: This is just one way, other ways might be possible just go through the flex-box docs thoroughly.

Comment: added flewGrow: 2 to the nested container and achieved the results I needed! the first link about flexbox helped!